# Behavior Subject Vs. Public?

Tags: angular, rxjs, components, behaviorsubject

We can use Behavior Subject to access a variable in more than 1 component, but I just discovered we can access variables in other components just by declaring them as "public" in the constructor of the files we wish to access them in.

Is Behavior Subject the preferred way to pass variable values between components, or can public be used instead / what are the drawbacks to using "public"?

**Method 1: Behavior Subject**

```
// To use Behavior Subject: 
// First, add the .service's name to the constructor() of both components.
// Next, add this code to your .service file: 
//    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    public loginPageErrorMessageSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);    // The (null) tells it to initialize the listener to "null"
//    changeLoginPageErrorMessage(message: any) {                             // To change the message / variable value, call this function from one of your .components (you can't call this function from within the same .service file)
//         this.loginPageErrorMessageSource.next(message)
//    }
//    loginPageErrorMessageChanges = this.loginPageErrorMessageSource.asObservable();   
//    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

then put this in the ngOnInit() of the component you wish to access the message changes in:

```
        this.loginPageErrorMessageChanges.subscribe(data => { 
              if(data !== undefined) { 
                     console.log(data) 
              } 
        })
```

**Method 2: Make the file public in the constructor**

-Say I have a sign-in.component.ts file and I wish to access the value of a variable in change-password.component.ts.

I would simply put this in the constructor() of change-password.component.ts:

```
constructor(public signInComponent: SignInComponent) { }
```

then print it in change-password.component.ts's ngOnInit():

```
ngOnInit() {
   console.log(this.signInComponent.variableIwantToAccess)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of how you're accessing variables between your components?

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Did you try this? When I try this I get `ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[SignInComponent -> SignInComponent -> SignInComponent]`

The SignInComponent isn't injectable.

Here is the code I tried:

**Component 1**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {
  variableIWantToAccess = "I want this value";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**Component 2**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SignInComponent } from '../sign-in/sign-in.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-change-password',
  templateUrl: './change-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./change-password.component.css']
})
export class ChangePasswordComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public signInComponent: SignInComponent) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.signInComponent.variableIWantToAccess)
  }

}
```

BTW - the services does not *have* to use a BehaviorSubject. It could just use a public property in the service to share that value with multiple components.

The BehaviorSubject is only needed if you want the service to provide push notifications.

**UPDATE**:
The follow up question requested clarification on:

> The BehaviorSubject is only needed if you want the service to provide push notifications.

If you want to store a value (like the user name) somewhere and access it when you need it, you can create a simple property in a service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  userName: string = '';

  constructor() { }
}
```

And access it from any component:

```js
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.userName = "New User Name"
  }

}
```

If you want the code to be notified every time the value changes, then use a BehaviorSubject. This is often used for user actions (such as selecting a drop down option) when you have code that needs to react to that change.

You can find a stackblitz example of this here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-property-vs-behaviorsubject-deborahk

Using a simple property, you can put a value into the service and later get it out of the service. This would work well for something like a user name that would be set one time and then accessed multiple times.

Using a BehaviorSubject, the code is notified any time the value changes. This is useful for anything that changes and the components need to be notified of the change, like a user preference or order quantity.

Comment: What do you mean by "if you want the service to receive push notifications"?

Comment: The above says `provide` push notifications not `receive` push notifications. See the clarification above.

Comment: @DeborahK we can replace push-notification by component communication ,I think it's more general